# Delete a rule within PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have created a rule using the following syntax:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] RULE name AS ON event
TO table [ WHERE condition ]
DO [ ALSO | INSTEAD ] { NOTHING | command | ( command ; command ... ) }
```

I now want to delete this rule and have been searching the documentation to explain how to do so, but I cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

`DROP RULE`

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droprule.html

Answer (score 2):

Starting with PostgreSQL 8.2, [the syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-droprule.html) is:

```
DROP RULE [ IF EXISTS ] name ON relation [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

Example:

```
DROP RULE newrule ON mytable;
```